# Rails Active Record select parent and child as one result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a parent / child relationship in my application

```
class Polling
 has_many :alerts, :dependent => :destroy

class Alert
 belongs_to :polling
```

On my index page for the alerts, I need to show some data from each parent, and this results in two queries

```
Alert Load (6.1ms)  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "ALERTS" INNER JOIN "POLLINGS" ON "POLLINGS"."ID" = "ALERTS"."POLLING_ID" ORDER BY "ALERTS"."ID" DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
Polling Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "POLLINGS".* FROM "POLLINGS" WHERE "POLLINGS"."ID" = 10113 AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

Obviously, this makes the page loading time quite horrendous as it has to loop through each one and pull the parent object as well.

I have tried a few things, such as

```
> Alert.joins(:polling).where(...)
> Alert.includes(:polling).where(...)
> Alert.joins(:polling).select('*').where(...)
```

And each time I get two distinct queries when I visit my index page. One for each Alert, and then another to get its parent data. How can I do this on one line so that when I pull the alerts I also get their associated parent data? There doesn't seem to be a way to go about it from the other end because if I do a `Pollings.where(...)` it doesn't grab the children as a group.

Comment: You're definitely on the right track with the includes method.  The other angle would be to try Polling.includes(:alerts).where(...).  Can you post your view code?

Comment: The thing is we have to go at it from the child side, not the parent side.

Comment: Don't you want preload? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AssociationPreload/ClassMethods/preload_associations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify SQL in detail, you can always try `find` method passing :include, :joins, :where etc. `includes` or `joins` does same thing down the line when you try to access to data but behaviour of activerecord is different. For example, following 3 ways set up object array but they are different.

[1]

```
alerts = Alert.joins(:polling)
```

[2]

```
alerts = Alert.includes(:polling)
```

[3]

```
alerts = Alert.find(:all, :includes => :polling, :joins => :polling)
```

when you do

```
alerts.each do |alert|
  alert.pollings.each do |polling|
    p polling
  end
end
```

you can see how activerecord tries to get data from DB or cache. The [3] way, I believe, throws only one query when others throw multiple queries.

Comment: I've found that even if I do the Alert.find with a join, if I use alert.pollings it still pulls those back seperately from the database, so that is what was causing it to still do the additional queries. I ended up using a .select() as well and just doing alert.polling_field works as intended. Weird, but it works.